# htaccess modify headers IF url ends with "news"

Tags: pages, htaccess

I have a wordress page that resolves to `/mysite/news` and I'm trying to load it onto another site using javascript. This is a natural cors violation so I'm setting cors to * to bypass the issue ONLY if the url is `/mysite/news`

However, the following isn't working. I suspect REQUEST_URI is actually resolving to something like `index.php?page=xxx` but I'm not sure. How can I get around this cors issue ?

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#news\/?$#">
  Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
  Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
  Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"
</If>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I suspect REQUEST_URI is actually resolving to something like `index.php?page=xxx`

Yes, it would seem that mod_rewrite is processed *before* the Apache Expression is evaluated. So, the URL has already been rewritten to `index.php` (the WordPress front-controller) before we get to evaluate the requested URL in the expression.

However, we can get around this by setting an environment variable "early" using `SetEnvif` based on the requested URL (which occurs *before* mod_rewrite) and check for this env var in the expression instead. HOWEVER, an added complication is that this env var is renamed/prefixed with `REDIRECT_` after the URL has been rewritten  (the first round of processing) to `index.php`.

For example:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "news/?$" APPLY_CORS
<If "-n reqenv('REDIRECT_APPLY_CORS')">
  Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
  Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
  Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"
</If>
```

`SetEnvIf` sets the `APPLY_CORS` env to `"1"` if the regex matches the request.

The `-n` operator in the Apache Expression simply tests that the returned string is not empty.

---

**UPDATE:** An alternative is to check against `THE_REQUEST` server variable instead, which contains the first line of the HTTP request (eg. `GET /mysite/news HTTP/1.1`<sup>***1**</sup>) and does not change as the URL is rewritten. A slight caveat with this is that the regex can be a little more complex.

<sup>(***1** - `THE_REQUEST` contains the raw, %-encoded URI as sent from the client, query string and all.)</sup>

For example, an equivalent to the above (which allows for any *reasonable* query string) would be something like:

```
<If "%{THE_REQUEST} =~ m#news/?(\?[\w=&-]*)?\s#">
:
</If>
```

Comment: I've added an alternative solution that uses `THE_REQUEST` instead - avoids the need for an additonal env var, at the expense of a marginally more complex regex.